# Concatenate cells but exclude empties in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am wondering how I can concatenate a row of cells with comma separated values but exclude empty cells.

For Example the list would be:

A1 - Dog

B1 - "empty cell"

C1 - Cat

I am looking for a formula that would return ---> Dog, Cat

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

With possible values in **A1, B1** and **C1**, in **D1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="","",A1)&IF(B1="","",IF(A1<>"",", "&B1,B1))&IF(C1="","",IF(AND(A1="",B1=""),C1,", "&C1))
```

This avoids using blanks and also avoids using unnecessary commas.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't have any built in functions that can do this, there are workarounds that end up with hard coded values that I don't really like.

Alternatively you could use a user defined function

```
Function comb_cells(r As Range, Optional delim As String = " ") As String

    For Each c In r
        If IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
        Else
            If Len(comb_cells) = 0 Then
                comb_cells = c.Value
            Else
                comb_cells = comb_cells & delim & c.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Then the formula would be

```
=comb_cells(A1:C1,", ")
```

Unfortunately user defined functions can be a pain since they won't work outside that workbook, or on other computers (depending on where it is saved) but I still think it would be your best bet.

This function takes a range that can include both rows and columns the for each command should loop the same way you would read (left to right, next row, left to right, etc).